# Python Change Button Image and change it back

Tags: python, image, button

so I have some code that changes the image of a button when clicked. Now, what if I wanted to only have the button change when it was clicked and then return back to normal? (Like a normal button) I can't just add another .config method as it will skip the first one and keep the button the same image. I can also not do a wait as it just freezes the program and produces the same result.

```
PlayUp = PhotoImage(file=currentdir+'\Up_image.gif')
PlayDown = PhotoImage(file=currentdir+'\Down_image.gif')
#Functions
def playButton():
    pButton.config(image=PlayDown)
    return

#Play Button
pButton = Button(root, text="Play", command=playButton)
pButton.grid(row=1)
pButton.config(image=PlayUp)
```

Comment: The strings `\U` and `\D` don't mean what you think they do. Try `r'\Up_image.gif'` for better results (or better still use os.path.join). Since you don't indicate what widget library you are using, it is hard to guess if there are any other problems.

Comment: Ok those were my image paths concatenated. Either way, I tried what you said and it still changes but doesn't change back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to make the button image change to look like a real button press but with images is to do something like this.

**Define your photos:**

```
PlayUp = PhotoImage(file=currentdir+r'\Up_image.gif')
PlayDown = PhotoImage(file=currentdir+r'\Down_image.gif')
```

**Define your functions:**

```
def returncolor():
    pButton.config(image=PlayUp)
def playButton():
    pButton.config(image=PlayDown)
    pButton.after(200,returncolor)
```

**Initialize Button:**

```
#Play Button
pButton = Button(root, text="Play", command=playButton, borderwidth=0)
pButton.grid(row=1)
pButton.config(image=PlayUp)
```